# Scala RDD[String] to RDD[String,String]

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, rdd, scala-collections

I have a `RDD[String]` which contains following data:

data format : `('Movie Name','Actress Name')`

```
('Night of the Demons (2009)  (uncredited)', '"Steff", Stefanie Oxmann Mcgaha')
('The Bad Lieutenant: Port of Call - New Orleans (2009)  (uncredited)', '"Steff", Stefanie Oxmann Mcgaha') 
('"Please Like Me" (2013) {All You Can Eat (#1.4)}', '$haniqua') 
('"Please Like Me" (2013) {French Toast (#1.2)}', '$haniqua') 
('"Please Like Me" (2013) {Horrible Sandwiches (#1.6)}', '$haniqua')
```

I want to convert this to `RDD[String,String]` such as first element within `' '` will be my first String in RDD and second element within `' '` will  be my second String in RDD.

I tried this:

```
val rdd1 = sc.textFile("/home/user1/Documents/TestingScala/actress"
val splitRdd = rdd1.map( line => line.split(",") )
splitRdd.foreach(println)
```

but it's giving me an error as :

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@7741fb9
[Ljava.lang.String;@225f63a5
[Ljava.lang.String;@63640bc4
[Ljava.lang.String;@1354c1de
```

Comment: That isn't an error message, that's the object-ids for a bunch of strings.

Comment: @Malvolio Can you please tell me how can I remove that error

Comment: Call `toList` on the result from `split`.

Answer (score 5):

> `[Ljava.lang.String;@7741fb9` is not an error, This is wt is printed
>   when you try to print an array.

`[` - an single-dimensional array

`L` - the array contains a class or interface

`java.lang.String` - the type of objects in the array

`@` - joins the string together

`7741fb9` the hashcode of the object.

> To print `String array` you can try this code:

```
import scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._
splitRdd.foreach(array => println(stringOf(array)))
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error. we could also use flatMap() here to avoid confusion,

```
val rdd1 = sc.textFile("/home/user1/Documents/TestingScala/actress"
rdd1.flatMap( line => line.split(",")).foreach(println)
```

Here, The input function to map returns a single element (array), while the flatMap returns a list of elements (0 or more). Also, the output of the flatMap is flattened.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is csv file with field-enclosed & row-enclosed, you need to read the file using regular expressions. Simple split doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert `RDD[String]` to `RDD[String,String]`

```
val rdd1 = sc.textFile("/home/user1/Documents/TestingScala/actress"
val splitRdd = rdd1.map( line => (line.split(",")(0), line.split(",")(1)) )
```

The above line returns the rdd as key, value pair [`Tuple`] RDD.